# Block Level Links with a absolute link overlay instead of a wrapping link?

Tags: html, css, hyperlink, accessibility, user-experience

### Teasers: block-level links or not?

Say you want to display a teaser inviting you to go see some more in-depth article on a new page. You can use a card component (`image` + `title` + `short intro`) to achieve that, and two solutions are then available to you:

1. Implement it the **simple** way: links are wrapping the image and the title. You could even have a "Read More" link at the bottom of the teaser.
2. Implement a **block-level link**: wrap the whole teaser inside a single link.

The two solutions are possible since forever ([HTML5 Doctor article by Bruce Lawson](http://html5doctor.com/block-level-links-in-html-5/)) and **should not cause too much problem** for screen reader users. Heydon Pickering also mentions block-level links in his book « Inclusive Design Patterns » and recommends not having too long text content inside a block-level link.

#### Accessibility issues

On a project I'm currently working on, I got a report from a screen reader user saying something a bit more nuanced. It is **confusing** for him to navigate across a group of block-level teasers, because everything is a link and it's therefore not clear what is the underlying action. Plus the screen reader keeps repeating you are inside a link.

When I tested with VoiceOver, the whole content of a block-level link is read, without any indication if it is reading a heading, an image or a paragraph. You have to willingly go inside the link to better understand. Maybe a `aria-labelledby` linked to the title could be useful.

---

### A link in absolute over the teaser

I came up with a solution that seems a bit dirty but should work on all cases with a link with `position: absolute` over the whole teaser. This implementation is actually the exact combination of the two solutions for a nice block-level linked teaser.

The absolute link is over the block and makes the teaser behave exactly the same way as a **block-level link**. For a screen reader user, links could also be added to the image+title and the absolute link contains a proper call to action text for screen readers only that will be read after the rest of the teaser content.

Another benefit of this implementation is the possibility to have other links inside the teaser and position them with a higher z-index over the link. This can be useful for the date/author/category for example.

---

My question is: **is this solution – compared to block-level links or the simple teaser with multiple links – a good idea in terms of a11y, UX and general code quality?**

Here is the teaser I'm talking about ([see on Codepen](http://codepen.io/tonifisler/pen/egLOZB)):

```css
.card-link-absolute {
  transition: all 0.2s;
  width: 20em;
  margin: 30px;
}
.card-link-absolute:hover {
  color: #014c8c;
  box-shadow: 0 0 4px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}
.card-link-overlay {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
.card-link-foreground {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 10;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<article class="card card-link-absolute">
  <img class="card-img-top" src="http://placehold.it/318x180" alt="Card image cap">
  <div class="card-block">
    <h4 class="card-title">Link in absolute</h4>
    <p class="card-text">The text is here and can be quite long</p>
    <p class="card-text">
      <a class="btn btn-success btn-sm card-link-foreground" href="http://antistatique.net">Other link</a>
    </p>
    <a href="#0" class="card-link-overlay"><span class="sr-only">Read more about Card title</span></a>
  </div>
</article>
```

Comment: 1. Regarding screen readers, some read out all the content (as you noted) but others not. 2. The absolute link is an okay idea but think of kbd users — should they see a focus style? 3. Also consider affordance for non-mouse users, such as touch users. If the teaser doesn't look like a link (there's no cursor change to see) will it be confusing?

Comment: How is the support for this overlay (in your code the `.card-link-overlay` anchor), looking at the hover event. Will the hover event of the underlying element (in your code the `article` element) also be triggered when you're basically hovering the overlay? In firefox @ ubuntu it does.

Answer (score 0):

My thoughts on the subject are : You can perfectly use the first solution (not wrapping everything inside a link) if this give a best screenreader experience. Then if you want to give mouse users another experience, you can use the javascript `onclick` event on the wrapper element with the "this-is-clickable" mouse pointer. As long as the same action can be performed using keyboard, nothing says that the links must be the same. This is nearly equivalent to your `position: absolute` solution, but easier to implement.

But I would have a reserve on that being really accessible. If it does not look like a link but behave like a link, it could be perturbing.

I would also say that if there are links inside which point to other destinations, it will be confusing for some people (with this implementation not specifically for screen reader users).